# Are bacteria necessary for an individual's life, or, how long could a person live without bacteria?

Tags: human-biology, bacteriology

Bacteria are essential to life in that they are responsible for breakdown of organic substances, etc. but are bacteria necessary for an *individual's* life?

In other words, how long would a human survive if they took a super-antibiotic which killed *all* the bacteria in their body, with the current state of medical technology? If they died what would be the most likely cause of death?

Assume bacteria don't recolonize your body.

Background: I call bacteria the "Lords of the Earth" both to remind myself to be humble and (rather more) as a conversation-starter. I'd like to be able to underline their importance in the ensuing discussions.

Comment: I grant that the "Background" sentence is opinion-based but it was just intended as a light-hearted introduction. The "How long" sentence was my real question and is IMHO factual. In any case anongoodnurse has answered to my satisfaction (and surprise). Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Do animal experiments really mean anything when it comes to extrapolating findings to humans?](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might need to demote your single-celled 'lords' to 'squires'. They're not essential to an individual's life. You wouldn't die (dispensing with the "how" right off the bat.) You'd be just fine if no bacteria reentered your body. Your fecal output would be greater; you would derive somewhat less nutrition from your food, you would need to take vitamin K, and there would be an adjustment period, but theoretically, you'd be just fine. You might even be healthier.

Your hypothetical is impossible, of course, because experimentation on humans is unethical. However, it might surprise you to learn that there are colonies of germ-free animals (also called *gnotobiotic*) used to study the effect of certain bacteria on animals.

The derivation of such subjects was initially fairly gruesome.

> The process of engineering biology and machine began by removing intact uteruses from near- to full-term pregnant animals within a purpose-built germ-free "surgical isolator." The uterus was subsequently passed through various disinfection procedures, involving total immersion in germicide-filled "dunk tanks," before the progeny were surgically released and hand reared within a second microbially sterile isolator.

These animals are costly to keep, as you can imagine. The originals must be delivered by Cesarean section, and housed and raised in sterile conditions. But once you can do that, they can multiply.

> To start a germ-free colony, one must remove a young animal from its mother’s womb through a careful surgical procedure to avoid exposing it to the microorganisms in the mother’s vagina and skin. Then, the animal is raised in a sterile cage and only exposed to food, water, and other equipment that has also been sterilized. On a weekly basis—or more often—a technician swabs cages and animal feces to ensure that no bacteria have contaminated the sterile housing. Once the colony has been created, it becomes easier to rear new germ-free animals; a germ-free mother can give birth naturally without exposing her newborns to any bacteria.

By the 1950s, researchers were rearing germ-free mice, rats, guinea pigs, and chicks inside sterile stainless steel (and later, plastic) housings. Germ-free animals are especially useful in researching, among other things, diabetes, auto-immune diseases, obesity, genetic engineering, cancer, immunology, nutrition, and the effects of normal intestinal flora on health.

Vitamin K must be added to their diets, and it is important to sterilize their food without destroying nutrients, but otherwise they do well in their environments. Their feces, of course, are sterile. Everything is microbe-free. They also have no "normal" antibodies.

Since generations of germ-free animals can exist and multiply, it is not only possible but quite likely that germ-free humans can exist as well.

Which is not to say that gut (and skin, etc.) microbiomes are unimportant. If you release a germ-free animal into a normal environment, it can die if it picks up pathogenic bacteria before more normal gut flora. To do this safely, a germ-free animal is first given a cocktail of bacteria to colonize the gut. After a while, they can be in a normal environment without problems. But your hypothetical human wouldn't even have this problem.

<sub>[Germ-Free Mice](http://irp.nih.gov/catalyst/v19i4/germ-free-mice)</sub>
<sub>[Gnotobiotics](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3918800/)</sub>
<sub>[Technology Highlights：ESTABLISHMENT OF THE FIRST GERMFREE MOUSE AND RAT COLONIES IN TAIWAN](http://www.narlabs.org.tw/en/pressroom/topic/topic.php?group_id=3&topic_id=1)</sub>
<sub>["Life in a Germ-Free World":
Isolating Life from the Laboratory Animal to the Bubble Boy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3477854/)</sub>

Comment: I am rather confused how you cited the 4th source, but didn't use its case study of the bubble boy.

Comment: @MarchHo - answered in Meta.

Comment: So finally, how long can humans live without bacteria? Is there any data on the longivity of such animals? Please include it in your answer. Do they live longer? Is the lifespan normal? Or is it short?

Comment: @CRags The life is definitely not NORMAL if normal means what is most common. Such a person may need to take a lot of dietary supplements. However, it is possible to keep that person alive as long as there are no other problems (independent of the said problem). It is same as: can a AIDS patient survive as long as their replica without AIDS -  yes, as long as they are kept in sterile environment

Comment: @WYSIWYG - their lives are "normal" compared to the controls, who also don't live a "normal" life. A better question is, What is the average lifespan of a patient with HIV on all the proper medications compared to one without HIV. Normal here applies to health, lifespan, etc., not activities in the wild.

Comment: Now it begins to sound as if bacteria-free humans would suffer from vitamin K deficiency (hemorrhaging?). After all, a question like "how long could you survive in a vacuum" would hardly be acceptably answered by "indefinitely, if you had an adequate spacesuit"

Comment: I am not asking about normalcy of life but lifespan. (That is the question?) Does the bacterial flora affect the lifespan? Many physiological processes are altered, due to sterile environment. So will this alteration increase / decrease or have no effect on lifespan? How do you relate HIV with this question? Patients with HIV have bacterial flora. And having HIV is not a part of normalcy.  HIV would actively work against host immunity, while absence of bacterial flora would result in a situation where no immunity reactions need occur. Please explain more @WYSIWYG. As the OP pointed out,

Comment: contd... let's say that all nutrients that are known as needed as of today are provided resulting in no deficiency of "known micro and macronutrients" for simplifying the answer.

Comment: @NL_Derek - Vitamin K is actually a group of compounds. The most important of these compounds appears to be vitamin K1 and vitamin K2. Vitamin K1 is obtained from leafy greens and some other vegetables. Vitamin K2 is a group of compounds largely obtained from meats, cheeses, and eggs, and synthesized by bacteria. No deficiency would necessarily occur.

Comment: @CRags I don't think loss of microflora would have any direct effect on lifespan. We don't even have enough cases to document the problems that may manifest because of living in sterile environment for a long time. Recent studies suggest the role of microflora on cancer (both positive and negative): this is mostly related to the biochemical reactions they carry out but we have insufficient data to say if their absence would make a great impact on the body except in case of nutrition. Low immunity on the other hand can also lead to cancer even in sterile environment